# Onmouseout and onmouseover combo not working to hide and display image

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="bhutu_kitten.jpg" alt="kitten bhutu" width="400" height="400" id="kitten" onmouseover=displayKitten() onmouseout=hideKitten() style="display: none">
    <img src="bhutu_baby.jpg" alt="baby bhutu" width="400" height="400" id="baby" onmouseover=hideBaby() onmouseout=displayBaby() style="display: block">

<script>
    function displayKitten(){
        document.getElementById("kitten").style.display='block';
    }
    function hideKitten(){
        document.getElementById("kitten").style.display='none';
    }
    function hideBaby(){
        document.getElementById("baby").style.display='none';
    }
    function displayBaby(){
        document.getElementById("baby").style.display='block';
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The purpose of the code is to by default show image1.

Onmouseover show image2.

onmouseout show image1.

But the code is not working as expected.Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of things that won't work. For example an element with `display: none` will never trigger the `onmouseover` because it's invisible. Or when you're hiding one image the other doesn't get shown - your code is just hiding the current one and that's it.

To make it work you can try something like this:

```js
function displayKitten(){
  document.getElementById("kitten").style.display='block';
  document.getElementById("baby").style.display='none';
}

function displayBaby(){
  document.getElementById("baby").style.display='block';
  document.getElementById("kitten").style.display='none';
}
```

```html
<img src="//lorempixel.com/400/300" 
     alt="kitten bhutu" 
     width="200" 
     height="200" 
     id="kitten" 
     onmouseover=displayBaby()>

<img src="//lorempixel.com/300/400" 
     alt="baby bhutu" 
     width="200"
     height="200" 
     id="baby" 
     onmouseout=displayKitten() 
     style="display: none">
```